# Accessing a SMB share without a password

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, smb, shared-directory

When accessing SMB shared that are password-protected, `smbclient` works just fine.

But when I'm trying to access shared that have no password protection (public shares), `smbclient` prints:

```
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

How can I access those shares?

I'm trying to access Windows 7 from my Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: are you _sure_ they are public shares?  Just because you can access a share from a windows machine with no password does not mean the share does not have one.

Comment: @iamkrillin - I manually tried accessing the share with password, and it worked. Then I removed the password, and it stopped working..

Comment: is the share on a windows machine or a *nix machine?

Comment: @iamkrillin - "I'm trying to access Windows 7 from my Ubuntu 12.10" - meaning the share is on my Windows